# Difficulty passing custom authentication token with Android SDK service feature request

Tags: android, arcgis, esri, arcgis-android-api

I am currently working on an Android application that utilizes the Esri Maps SDK. In my application, I need to pass a custom authentication token along with the service feature request to the server. However, I initially encountered an error while attempting to pass the auth token using the credential method.

Here is the current Android implementation code:

```
val serviceUrl = "service_url"
val authToken = "auth_token"

with(ServiceFeatureTable(serviceUrl)) {
    val credential = UserCredential.createFromToken(
        authToken,
        "dummy_referer"
    )
    this.credential = credential

    // Define the request mode to manual
    featureRequestMode =
        ServiceFeatureTable.FeatureRequestMode.MANUAL_CACHE

    // Load the ServiceFeatureTable and set it as the feature layer's data source
    addDoneLoadingListener {
        if (loadStatus == LoadStatus.LOADED) {
            // Query time extent
            queryTimeExtent(this, completionCallback, startTimeMilli, endTimeMilli)
        } else {
            completionCallback?.onError(loadError)
        }
    }

    trackFeatureLayer = FeatureLayer(this).apply {
        id = "user_map"

        addDoneLoadingListener {
            if (loadStatus == LoadStatus.LOADED) {
                /*  mapView?.setViewpointAsync(Viewpoint(fullExtent))
                            completionCallback?.onSuccess(visible)*/
            } else {
                completionCallback?.onError(loadError)
            }
        }

        // add the feature layer to the map's operational layers
        mapView?.map?.operationalLayers?.add(this)
    }
}
```

When I send the request using the iOS SDK, I can successfully include the authentication token, and the server receives it as expected. However, when I attempt to send the same token using the Android SDK, the received request on the server side does not include the token.

I have already ensured that I'm correctly passing the authentication token using credentials without encountering any errors. The issue seems to be specific to the Android SDK.

I have also posted a question on the Esri Community forum regarding this issue, which can be found at [link to the Esri Community question](https://community.esri.com/t5/kotlin-maps-sdk-questions/need-help-passing-authentication-token-to/m-p/1287422#M31).

Is there any solution or workaround available to successfully pass the custom authentication token with the service feature request using the Android SDK? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.